# Store data in One to Many relationships

Tags: laravel

I have a saved model User:
id | name | location_id

and unsaved Model location:
id |city| country| lat| lng

Model User

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Location');        

}
```

Model Location

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }
```

How can i save locations data in locations table and location_id to related user in one query?

Comment: You cannot perform this in one query, it will always be two database queries that are performed (because you are querying two tables). Only when you add a new user to a location it can be performed in one query.

Comment: then what i have to do?hanks

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
 you should rename the *user* method in your Location model to be *users*

**Second:**

assuming you have a saved Location and want to save a User for him, you can do it like this:

```
$location->users()->save($user);
```